# Retrieve gif image from firebase and returns the same gif image, how to fix this?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I have a problem with my app,
I am currently building an information page with a horizontal slider using ViewPager. I have 2 layout XML which is united with 1 activity with ViewPager, which means that each layout displays a different gif. All gif images are retrieved from firebase. The problem is all the layout displays the same gif.

Here my onCreate function :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_practice)

    val gifImage1 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("gif/step1.gif")
    val gifImage2 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("gif/step2_left.gif")
    val localFile = File.createTempFile("tempGif", "gif")

    gifImage1.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {
        val gifFromPath = GifDrawable(localFile.absolutePath)
        img.setImageDrawable(gifFromPath)
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to retrieve the image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    gifImage2.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {
        val gif2FromPath = GifDrawable(localFile.absolutePath)
        img2.setImageDrawable(gif2FromPath)
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to retrieve the image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    
    init()
    dataSet()
    interaction()
}
```

Below my sample layout XML :
[image]

Screenshot for first layout XML below :
[image]

Screenshot for second layout XML below :
[image]

The two layouts above should have different gif image.
Any help and solution, I am very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same `localFile` for both images.

```
val localFile = File.createTempFile("tempGif", "gif")
```

You should download them to separate files instead of using the same file.

Comment: thanks, but is there a best way to write this code? to avoid repetition of writing code

Comment: Yes. That is called a loop.